# Why does 0.00 evaluates to true?

Tags: php

I wanted to write a very simple function display some values only if they evaluate to true. So I wrote the piece of code below, and some test function calls...

```
function value_fff($value = false)
{
    return $value ? $value : '';
}

echo value_fff('fsdfsdf') . '<br />';
echo value_fff('0.00') . '<br />';
echo value_fff('0') . '<br />';
echo value_fff(false) . '<br />';
echo value_fff(null) . '<br />';
echo value_fff('1') . '<br />';
echo value_fff() . '<br />';
echo value_fff(true) . '<br />';
```

My problem is that I get the following values:

```
fsdfsdf
0.00



1

1
```

So, it's obvious that 0.00 evaluates to true... Why is that happening? Indeed I'm in a locale that decimal separator is `,` instead of `.`, but is it that? And if yes, how am I supposed to deal with it?

Comment: because the 0.00 you use is string and it was considered true since the variable is not empty, try converting it to number it will become false

Comment: But `$value` comes from an XML (while importing some records), so it's always cast as string, that's why I wrote it like `'0.00'` instead of `0.00`. Consequently, I can't simply cast `$value` to `(float)`, because in other cases, it'll be a normal string. So I want to dim the comparison `false` if `$value` is empty, or some value that evaluates to a number, where that number evaluates to false (0 / 0.00 / etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function value_fff($value = false)
{
    if (is_numeric($value)) { $value += 0; }
    return $value ? $value : '';
}
```

tried adding `is_numeric()` to check if the string is number then we're gonna add it to 0 just to make it a number.

Comment: This seems to get the job done! It doesn't look very elegant, but indeed it did the trick! So thank you very much for it. PS: I loved the brilliant way to making it a number by adding 0 to it, instead of `cast`ing it to `int` or `float`, or `floatval`ing or `intval`ing it!

Comment: yes, you can simplify it I just coded it on the spot.

Comment: By _simplify_ it you mean to use two nested ternary `if`s instead of the normal if/elseif ?

Comment: I updated my code, I just remove some unnecessary condition